# qcow2 disk not showing in disk utility when installing macOS

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, qcow2

I am trying to install macOS (catalina) on ubuntu in virtual machine. I followed this tutorial [install macOS on ubuntu](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-run-macos-inside-a-virtual-machine-on-linux-4d6ce7cd493e)

everything is working up to macOS Utilities page as described, issue is my root and home are on different hard disk. root is in SSD and home is at hd. So under disk utility it is not showing the qcow2 image which I have created at \home. It is only showing disk under Internal. Show All devices also shows only two disks one of 2GB ie the baseimg file and another of some MBs. I have created a 70GB qcow file at home folder. How can install the macOS at home which is on another disk.

Comment: Sounds like the MAC OS install wont let you do what you are trying to do. Not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: @David there is no way to list home files (on different hd) during installation ?

Comment: I have no idea that is really a MAC OS question.

Answer (score 1):

resolved Issue was command typo error it was running sh file but due to typo error  was not recognizing the disk installed successfully